# How to apply retopology

Tags: topology

After making retopology with a plane, what should I do then? Should I delete the original mesh or is there some option to apply that new topology over the old one. In videos that I watched nobody really described what's after that.

Comment: Hello :). Would you please add some images to better illustrate your question?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand :). Retopology - like changing tris into quads *immediately replaces* the old topology. They don't exist both at the same time. Consider linking the videos you mentioned, to make your question more clear :).

Comment: Here is one from flipped normals: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuQzPDs99yM

Comment: Right, I see :). They literally *recreate* the whole model using quads, starting with one polygon. Their old mesh is only used as a guide - it's a different object. There's no *applying* the new topology, because the whole model is recreated. Is it a bit more clear now?

Comment: Yes, do you might know how can I do retopology on just a part of a mesh?

Comment: Well... You can just delete the part of your mesh you don't like, and then continue with the same approach from the video. Or, if you already made your retopologized area elsewhere, just connect it with new faces to the old mesh. Apologies if some of this is already clear to you :).